# (dict class) is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, serialization, data-processing

I am trying to update a code written in Python 2 to Python 3. This code is reading data from a file, and then it does some data processing.

```
RecordID,SAPS-I,SOFA,Length_of_stay,Survival,In-hospital_death
132539,6,1,5,-1,0
132540,16,8,8,-1,0
132541,21,11,19,-1,0
132543,7,1,9,575,0
132545,17,2,4,918,0
```

The error is pointing to this section:

```
            try:
            print("trying to parse ID")
            print(type(id_))
            parse_id(id_)
```

and the it is executes `parse_id`:

```
label = out.loc[int(id_)]
rec = {'label': label}

rec['forward'] = parse_rec(values, masks, evals, eval_masks, dir_='forward')
rec['backward'] = parse_rec(values[::-1], masks[::-1], evals[::-1], eval_masks[::-1], dir_='backward')
print("reached json.dumps")
print(type(rec))
rec = json.dumps(rec)
print("after dump")

fs.write(rec + '\n')
```

`parse_id` is executing `parse_rec`

```
def parse_rec(values, masks, evals, eval_masks, dir_):
    deltas = parse_delta(masks, dir_)

    # only used in GRU-D
    forwards = pd.DataFrame(values).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0.0).to_numpy() #changed as_matrix to .values

    rec = {}

    rec['values'] = np.nan_to_num(values).tolist()
    rec['masks'] = masks.astype('int32').tolist()
    # imputation ground-truth
    rec['evals'] = np.nan_to_num(evals).tolist()
    rec['eval_masks'] = eval_masks.astype('int32').tolist()
    rec['forwards'] = forwards.tolist()
    rec['deltas'] = deltas.tolist()

    return rec
```

So `values`, `masks`, `evals`, and `eval_masks` are: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

and here is the error:

```
trying to parse ID
<class 'str'>
reached json.dumps
<class 'dict'>
0 is not JSON serializable
```

I tried different ways suggested on Stack, such as .decode('utf-8'), but they were not suitable for the class str data type.
This is a part of a value of `rec`

```
{'label': 0, 'forward': {'values': [[0.0, -0.49034524123312234, 0.0, 0.0, 1.6507596063107246, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.46547721054525065, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.1109460541475529, 0.0, 0.5392164059229704, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.09444392939859172, 1.4748633585670563, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.5214635171496661, -0.3991306007085636, -0.6247258127605516, 2.0491463305338438, 0.0, -1.1073548857099629, 0.0,
```

Comment: Not sure why you think `id_` is very relevant here…? What is `rec`‽

Comment: can you print the value and type of `rec` just before call to json.dump. Ideally, post [mre], incl. full traceback you get

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the question. @deceze

Comment: We still don’t know what `rec` really is. Some value within it isn’t serializable.

Comment: I added a part of that. @buran

Comment: Now, it turns that `rec` is `dict`, not `str` and you even changed also [the error in] the title. And for your information `dict` IS json serializable, Please, post your code - [mre] and full traceback. There is no point to guess.

Comment: @buran yes, thank you for the comment. I tried to edit it to make it clear. I am very new to Python.